Python script parameter not working as it supposed to
I tried to use on my MacBook a script I found that does 1. changes some filters of an imported image and 2. changes the metadata of it. After adjusting a bit it worked but the metadata did not change using the parameters from the script as you can see. (On the left is the original image and on the right is the exported one by the script). My point is, how can the data that is written on the script be applied? (a random device name, a random creation date etc). Any other improvement is welcome please.
https://iili.io/dGc8nBj.jpg
The script code i used:
import os
import random
import shutil
from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance, ImageFilter
import piexif
import datetime


def clean_photo(photo_path, output_path):
    # Load the photo
    photo = Image.open(photo_path)

    if "exif" in photo.info:
        exif_dict = piexif.load(photo.info["exif"])
        exif_dict.clear()
        exif_bytes = piexif.dump(exif_dict)
        photo_info = photo.info.copy()
        photo_info["exif"] = exif_bytes
    else:
        photo_info = photo.info.copy()

    photo.info["Location"] = "United States"

    exposure = random.randint(-2, 2)
    brilliance = random.randint(-2, 2)
    highlights = random.randint(-2, 2)
    contrast = random.randint(-2, 2)
    brightness = random.randint(-2, 2)
    saturation = random.randint(-2, 2)
    vibrancy = random.randint(-2, 2)

    margin_pixels = random.randint(5, 20)  # Number of pixels to cut from each margin
    width, height = photo.size
    left = margin_pixels
    upper = margin_pixels
    right = width - margin_pixels
    lower = height - margin_pixels
    photo = photo.crop((left, upper, right, lower))
    photo = photo.filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur(radius=random.randint(1, 3)))

    camera_make = random.choice(["Canon", "Nikon", "Sony", "Fuji"])
    camera_model = random.choice(["Model A", "Model B", "Model C"])

    if "exif" in photo.info:
        exif_dict = piexif.load(photo.info["exif"])
        exif_dict["0th"][piexif.ImageIFD.Make] = camera_make
        exif_dict["0th"][piexif.ImageIFD.Model] = camera_model
    else:
        exif_dict = {"0th": {piexif.ImageIFD.Make: camera_make, piexif.ImageIFD.Model: camera_model}}
    exif_bytes = piexif.dump(exif_dict)
    photo_info["exif"] = exif_bytes

    random_date = datetime.datetime(
        random.randint(2000, 2021),
        random.randint(1, 12),
        random.randint(1, 28),
        random.randint(0, 23),
        random.randint(0, 59),
        random.randint(0, 59)
    )
    creation_date = random_date.strftime("%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S")

    if "exif" in photo_info:
        exif_dict = piexif.load(photo_info["exif"])
        exif_dict["0th"][piexif.ImageIFD.DateTime] = creation_date.encode("utf-8")
    else:
        exif_dict = {"0th": {piexif.ImageIFD.DateTime: creation_date.encode("utf-8")}}
    exif_bytes = piexif.dump(exif_dict)
    photo_info["exif"] = exif_bytes

    random_filename = ''.join(random.choices('01234567890', k=10))
    filename, ext = os.path.splitext(photo_path)
    output_filename = f"IMG_{random_filename}{ext}"

    output_file_path = os.path.join(output_path, output_filename)
    photo.save(output_file_path)


def clean_photos(main_folder, usedpics_folder, num_iterations):
    output_folder = os.path.join(main_folder, "CleanedPics")
    os.makedirs(output_folder, exist_ok=True)

    usedpics_path = os.path.join(main_folder, usedpics_folder)
    usedpics = os.listdir(usedpics_path)

    for i in range(num_iterations):
        iteration_folder = os.path.join(main_folder, f"Iteration_{i+1}")
        os.makedirs(iteration_folder, exist_ok=True)

        for usedpic in usedpics:
            usedpic_path = os.path.join(usedpics_path, usedpic)
            clean_photo(usedpic_path, iteration_folder)


main_folder = "/Users/macpro/Downloads/script”
usedpics_folder = “used”

num_iterations = 5

clean_photos(main_folder, usedpics_folder, num_iterations)

(https://i.sstatic.net/xFW4Eg5i.jpg)
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/82xalqTK.jpg

You are explicitly making a copy of photo.info, and then applying all of your metadata changes to that copy.  At no point are you actually setting any metadata of the actual image that you're saving to disk.
